# Create a database in python where user inputs the data?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I would like the program to ask the user for information (i.e. age and name) and for this information to be put into the database.

I have tried the following:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("Students.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE age_name ( 
age INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,   
name VARCHAR(50));"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)
for s in range(0,20):
    student_name=input('Students Name: ')
    student_age=input(' Students Age: ')
    new_data = ("""INSERT INTO age_name (student_age, student_name)
    VALUES ({},{});""".format(age,name))
    cursor.execute(new_data)
```

The error that keeps appearing is:

```
cursor.execute(new_data)
OperationalError: no such column: 'James'
```

I have Python 3.7 and I work in spyder.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your code, ```.format(student_age,student_name)```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it however the error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("Students.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE age_name ( 
age INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,   
name VARCHAR(50));"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)
for s in range(0, 20):
    student_name = input('Students Name: ')
    student_age = input(' Students Age: ')
    new_data = ("""INSERT INTO age_name (age, name)
    VALUES ({},'{}');""".format(student_age, student_name))
    cursor.execute(new_data)
```

**student_name** is a string and should be enclosed in **single quotes**.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sushanth rightly pointed out, you should change the ".format(age,name))" in your code to ".format(student_age,student_name))".
In addition (although off your question), you shouldn't make age a primary key.

Comment: Thanks, although can you explain why age shouldn't be a primary key.

Comment: Also I noticed that age is an integer, so cast the age to an integer before passing it to the db. I mean do something like student_age =  int(input('Students Age'))

Comment: @YimJohns, why should age be casted to integer ?

Comment: @May Breaker, it's possible to have 2 or more students who are of same age. In that way, the column is no more unique, which is one of the attributes of a primary key.

Comment: @Sushanth, the age in the table is of an integer type, rather than varchar

Comment: @YimJohns, as you pointed yes students can exists with same age. But that is not the scope of the question, Here OP has issue saving the data.

Comment: @Sushanth, yes, kindly check through the first comment I made where I quoted you, i did include in brackets "(although off your question)".